# Prepend WWW to sitemap Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-sitemaps

My urls are without WWW, how do I add it?

```
<url>
<loc>https://website.com/t/483/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

I use the [Django sitemaps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/).

Since I force www on all my website

I have the following in my settings,py

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
SITE_ID = 1
```

And in my urls.py

```
from home.sitemaps import TitleSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'titles': TitleSitemap,
}
```

and I have a sitemaps.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from title.models import Title

class TitleSitemap(Sitemap):

    changefreq = 'daily'
    protocol = 'https'

    def items(self):
        return Title.objects.filter(error_code__isnull=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Comment: you need to do it from nginx and not django sitemap

Comment: @Exprator nope, this is django-generated content.

Comment: yeah i know @brunodesthuilliers but django never appends https, as it comes from the ssl and www will also come from that.

Comment: What's your `Site.objects.get_current().domain` value ?

Comment: @Exprator still wrong - as you can find out by yourself by generating a sitemap while running on the dev server. And yes, Django DOES add the url scheme here, based on the incoming HTTP request.

Comment: @Exprator I have added protocol='https' to the sitemap class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to solve this by just changing the Domain Name value in the Admin page. So, if you have

**Domain Name:** example.com

Replace it with:

**Domain Name:** www.example.com